# glfw cursor pos callback returns irregular values

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, cursor-position

This is the glfwPollEvents() callback function for mouse cursor and the other method I use to check how much my cursor moved between frames.

```
void Window::HandleMouse(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos) {
        Window* window_ptr = static_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
        if (window_ptr->mouse_first_moved) {
            window_ptr->xlast = xpos;
            window_ptr->ylast = ypos;
            window_ptr->mouse_first_moved = false;
        }
        window_ptr->xchange = xpos - window_ptr->xlast;
        window_ptr->ychange = window_ptr->ylast - ypos;
        window_ptr->xlast = xpos;
        window_ptr->ylast = ypos;
    }

    GLfloat Window::GetXChange() {
        static GLfloat change_x;
        change_x = xchange;
        xchange = 0;
        return change_x;
    }
```

These values is what GetXChange returns when called in the render loop during one mouse "shake" (I moved it fairly quickly to the right and left trying to keep the movement speed constant). What they mean is how much my mouse covered in the x axis between one frame and the other.

```
12.0
4.0
59.0
8.0
3.0
1.0
-1.0
-2.0
-46.0
-64.0
-61.0
-47.0
-21.0
```

My first guess was that my framerate isn't stable but after checking it I found that it wasn't the case.

What could be the reason for such discrepancy?

Comment: How many times do you call  `Window::GetXChange`?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Only once every loop